# How to match count of column and if greater than 2 then update table in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, select, sql-update

Input table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH6W3.jpg
Output table i want 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCb9.jpg

I tried this way

```
update tb set Exception = 'Y'
select Card_No from tb
where Card_No in ( select Card_No from (select Card_No count(Left(Card_No,6)) from tb
group by Card_No having count(*)>=2)a);
```

above query giving me op this way
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ47z.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
update mytable 
set exception = case when cnt > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
from (
    select substring(card_no, 1, 6) sub_card_no, count(*) cnt 
    from mytable
    group by 1
) t
where t.sub_card_no = substring(mytable.card_no, 1, 6)
```

I might be more efficient to use window functions:

```
update mytable 
set exception = case when cnt > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
from (
    select card_no, count(*) over(partition by substring(card_no, 1, 6)) cnt 
    from mytable
) t
where t.card_no = mytable.card_no
```